# Function for making a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm reading Python Crash Course and doing tasks from chapter 8 (Functions). Can't understand one thing. This is code (#1):

```
def make_car(manufacturer, model_name, **car_info): 
    car_info['manufacturer'] = manufacturer
    car_info['model name'] = model_name
    return car_info

car = make_car('subaru', 'outback', color='blue', tow_package=True)
print(car)
```

This is output:

```
{'color': 'blue', 'tow_package': True, 'manufacturer': 'subaru', 'model name': 'outback'}
```

I get what I need – a dictionary. The data is stored in the dictionary `car_info`.

This is another block of code (#2):

```
def make_car(manufacturer, model, **options):
    """Make a dictionary representing a car."""
    options = {
    'manufacturer': manufacturer.title(),
    'model': model.title(),
    }
    for option, value in options.items():
        options[option] = value

    return options

my_outback = make_car('subaru', 'outback', color='blue', tow_package=True)
print(my_outback)
```

I think data should be stored in options, and output should be the same as the previous one. But it isn't. I’m getting this:

```
{'manufacturer': 'Subaru', 'model': 'Outback'}
```

Can someone explain why code #2 doesn't provide the same result as code #1? It has to store all data in `options` (just like code #1 stores in `car_info`).

This change helps (code #3):

```
def make_car(manufacturer, model, **options):
    """Make a dictionary representing a car."""
    car_dict = {
        'manufacturer': manufacturer.title(),
        'model': model.title(),
        }
    for option, value in options.items():
        car_dict[option] = value

    return car_dict
```

But I don't understand why we need `car_dict` if in code #1 it worked fine with `car_info`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In block of code #2 you wrote:

```
def make_car(..., ..., **options): ...
    options = {
        ...
    }
```

That is, you accepted an `options` dict as a parameter,
and then you ignored it,
choosing to overwrite it instead with a brand new dictionary.
Don't do that.

Name your local variable something else,
such as `car_dict`,
which from block of code #3 we can see is winning.